# Как сделать сортировку изображений по возрастанию?

Tags: php

```
$folder = 'photo'; // папка с картинками  
$max = 1; 
if(is_dir($folder))  
{  
        if($dir = opendir($folder))  
        {  
                while($file = readdir($dir))  
                {  
                        if($file !="." && $file !="..")  
                        {  
                                $images[] = $file;  
                        }  
                }  
                closedir($dir);  
        }else echo 'Невозможно открыть каталог';  
}else echo 'Файл не является директорией';

$amount = count($images);  
$pages = ceil($amount/$max);

$p = $_GET['page'];

if(!$p OR $p=='')  
{  
        $nmin = 0;  
        $nmax = $max - 1;  
}else{  
        $nmin = ($p * $max) - $max;  
        $nmax = ($max * $p) - 1;  
}

# Вывод фотографий  
for($i = $nmin; $i <= $nmax; $i++)  
{

         if($images[$i])   
        {   
                echo '<img  src="'.$folder.'/'.$images[$i].'"/>';
                 echo "</br></br>";
                 echo ''.$images[$i].'';
        }
}  
# Навигация  
echo "</br></br>";

for ($n=1; $n<=$pages; $n++)  
{  
        if($p != $n)  
        { 
                echo '<a href="index.php?page='.$n.'">['.$n.']</a>'; 
        }  
        elseif ($p !== $n)  
        { 
                echo '['.$n.']'; 
        }

}
```

Пробовал

```
 $image = array(
        '4.jpg',
        '1.jpg',
        '12.gif',
        '11.hpg',
    );
    natsort($image);
    print_r($image);
```

Не получается. Как это прикрутить к выше указанному скрипту?

**Обновление**

Делал так, возникла проблема, выводит `photo/1.jpg`, а нужно `1.jpg`.

```
$folder = glob("photo/*.*");
natsort($folder);

foreach($folder as $file)
$images[] = $file;
```

Comment: А у меня получилось.

    $image = array(
            '4.jpg',
            '1.jpg',
            '12.gif',
            '11.hpg',
        );
        natsort($image);
        print_r($image);

    Array ( [1] => 1.jpg [0] => 4.jpg [3] => 11.hpg [2] => 12.gif )

Comment: я не это спрашиваю

Comment: @Bridun Возможно, Вы имели ввиду **по убыванию**:

    $image = array(
            '4.jpg',
            '1.jpg',
            '12.gif',
            '11.hpg',
    );
    rsort($image, SORT_NUMERIC);
    
    print_r($image);

Comment: я имл ввиду как это прикрутить к вышеуказаному скрипту

Comment: Вставить строку
 
   $images = natsort($images);// Вот эту строку
   $amount = count($images);  
   $pages = ceil($amount/$max);

Comment: Спасибо, но так не работает. Обновил вопрос.